# Console Logging in Spring Boot with undertow embedded server

Tags: spring-boot, undertow, access-log

I am trying to get access log of an embedded undertow server from spring boot > 2.0 to stdout of an container. With embedded tomcat spring properties can work, but the same does not for undertow server. I tried modifying server.undertow.accesslog.* properties and tried configuring directory to
/dev/stdout but unfortunately this error out.

Any suggestions how can I redirect undertow access logs to console?

Answer (score 0):

```
server.undertow.accesslog.enabled=true
server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=<PATTERN>
server.undertow.accesslog.dir=/dev
server.undertow.accesslog.prefix=stdout
server.undertow.accesslog.suffix=
server.undertow.accesslog.rotate=false
```

This should work for you. Please **don't** add empty braces for suffix like this ""

Comment: Where do these configuration lines go?

Comment: in your application.properties / application.yaml file, syntax for .properties and .yaml file are different. The ones that i mentioned are for application.properties file.